# Changing Hostname and Serving with Apache

Tags: networking, hostname

I want to serve my website locally with my hostname. It's gibberish now, but people in my network can reach it. Let's say my hostname is

```
>hostname
ABCabcABC
```

And, if my local people open a browser and open `http://ABCabcABC`, they can reach my website.

I want my website to be reached at, let's say, `http://aaa`

I tried changing my hostname with `hostname` command. It didn't work.

I tried to make a new VirtualHost file and typed a new 'ServerName` value, but it didn't work either.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you hosting your own DNS? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/270080/set-up-domain-name-on-private-server :)

Comment: @Rinzwind No, I am not, I guess. It's a local network. 4-5 people are connected to same network.

Comment: Then you probably already have a dns running somewhere (or bind9) and you need to change it on that machine (from memory I would believe Rudu got it correct).

Comment: @Rinzwind and how is our favourite wizard, living in interesting times? :)

Comment: @rudu very busy with work :P

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to provide domain name service to your network so the computers now how to turn names into IP addresses.

1) Setup a DNS server which you can link `aaa` to the machine, and get every computer on the network to use this DNS server for resolution.  You can also set it up to cache web entries so it gives a slight performance improvement to your network, and it allows you to add other names in the future.

2) Add to the `/etc/hosts` file (or `hosts` on windows) that `aaa` resolves to a certain IP.  Same immediate effect as above in resolving `aaa` but no other benefits, if you want to add `bbb` you'd have to visit each machine again.

The `hostname` setting is only the name the computer things of itself as, it doesn't help any other computer on the network find it by name.

There is actually a third option, if you're using a custom DHCP server (ie. not a router, but a *nux based daemon) you can pair your DHCP server with your DNS server so when hosts are assigned IP addresses their name and IP is automatically added to the DNS server... this effectively allows connection by the `hostname` file.

There are some lightweight DNS servers on the market I've not tried, the big two heavyweights are `PowerDNS` and `Bind`

Methods 1 & 2 allow you to point multiple names to the same computer, method 3 allows the first name to automatically get registered, but you'd have to manually edit zones (as in method 1) to have multiple domains point to the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

This spells the DNS issue.  Setting up your own DNS servers is quite a complicated and time-consuming process, because you are required to have 2 physical machines with its own IP address and is different from each other's IPs before DNS could work.

As a quick and easy fix - outsource your DNS needs to DNS provider.  I am very happy with https://dnsimple.com/ and this is the best service at very reasonable rate.  And it is one of the best company after trying 5 different companies.

Besides, check my article regarding virtual hosting on apache2.  I included the formatted working structure of directives.  Maybe that'll help you somehow.

https://serverfault.com/questions/560611/multiple-web-servers-behind-one-public-ip/560622?noredirect=1#comment650553_560622

Comment: There's plenty of guides to help do exactly this, setting up DNS really isn't a big deal.  You're confusing public DNS for a domain (*recommended* multiple machines with IPs in different subnets - not required) with private DNS.  What's needed here is private & caching only.  If outsourcing to a DNS service your private network topology is going to be publicly exposed.

Comment: I stand corrected. (Thanks @Rudu). Use your hostname as an address and it'll run. I.e. your hostname "myHost", and enter 'myHost' inside your http on your browser, and it'll run fine on local network.